# "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" unneeded now that long chats are folded?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

This message would almost make sense to me except for the fact that chat discussions are hid by default and you must click show all.

I'm revisiting [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments) but did not find any explanation of what harm hidden chats are doing in that thread.

To reiterate old gripes, 95% of the time I've seen this I've ignored it. The discussions are always about the answer or question at hand. Happens a bit more often on meta especially in the case of explaining reasoning behind policy to a new user.  To be fair I always *consider* the suggestion, before thinking, "No, that's stupid."

Comment: Yeah I don't really think it's working. We recently deleted a 399-comment thread that could have easily passed off as a Skype conversation.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn So how's your day going BoltClock?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I guess I could have flipped this into "users ignore this message since it seems pointless to them" and taken the other side with the exact same logic.

Comment: @Servy: It's not even an hour into Wednesday and I can already tell it's going to suck.

Comment: I think we should have a Skype convo to prove OP right/wrong..

Answer (score 9):

I've seen a *lot* of long comment threads that *aren't* about improving the post.  Some of them aren't even about the topic of the site after a while.  It's possible that this behavior is site-specific.  (I see it a lot on the more "subjective" sites, in particular.)

A reader should be able to read through the comments that are about the post (even if numerous and behind a "show N comments") link, but too much junk mixed in there deters readers.  It also makes work for moderators, who are the only ones (other than the authors) who can delete comments -- which we can only do *one at a time* or by flushing *everything*.

Experienced users may tune out the warning, but I believe it does deter some newer users (who want to do what's right but don't know what that is), and the cost of having that message is pretty low.

So I think the current behavior is fine.